# Did Chopin Op. 6 have four or five pieces?

Tags: chopin, editions

On [IMSLP](https://imslp.org/wiki/Mazurkas,_Op.6_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazurkas,_Op._6_(Chopin)) they only list four, but I found some sources that have a fifth one as well such as [here](https://chopin.nifc.pl/en/chopin/kompozycja/148) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UDYXb0pyrnU). What is with the discrepancy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first editions of Frédéric Chopin's *Muzurkas*, Opp. 6 & 7 were published in (1833) Leipzig, as works of 4 and 5 pieces respectively.

The last piece of Op. 7 (№ 5 *Vivo* in C major) was moved to Op. 6 for a Paris edition† which came later.

This is explained at the bottom of the [IMSLP page for Op. 7](https://imslp.org/wiki/Mazurkas,_Op.7_(Chopin,_Fr%C3%A9d%C3%A9ric)):

> *The 5th Mazurka appeared in Op.7 only in the first Leipzig edition. It was issued as the 5th item in Op.6 of the Paris edition.

It's also mentioned (in passing) at the top of a link in your question; the [TFCI page for Op. 6 No. 5](https://chopin.nifc.pl/en/chopin/kompozycja/148):

> The Mazurka in C major that closes Opus 6 in the Paris edition (Opus 7 in the Leipzig edition) is an oberek.

You can also find this piece listed on the [Wikipedia page for Op. 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mazurkas,_Op._7_(Chopin)).

---

† Apparently this is not the same as the (c. 1916–22) Paris edition that can be found on IMSLP.